# Responsibilities of Delegates and Controllers in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm new to development on the iPhone.  Just about every sample project (as well as the default project templates) have one or more delegates and controllers.  Can someone give me a breakdown of what the delegates are responsible for vs. what the controllers are supposed to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way I can think to differentiate the two are:

- A delegate is a protocol (interface) that defines methods that an object implements in order to receive specific messages from other objects.  Delegates objects are most often used to receive asynchronous callbacks such as user input, I/O.
- A controller is an object that usually contains UI elements (views, controls, etc.) and data, and both receives and send messages to the various objects within it.  In many cases, a controller **is** a delegate and can implement several delegate protocols to receive events from multiple objects.

Keep in mind that many UI elements and controls let you pass events back to the controller by linking them to an IBAction method in Interface Builder.  This is very handy as it doesn't require extra code to implement delegates.  However, some other APIs such as the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController or NSURLConnection have no visualization in Interface Builder and so must use delegates to handle their events.

Answer (score 4):

A delegate is some object that implements a set of methods which either your application or the framework you link against depends on for functioning.  It is a means of implementing a delegation based design pattern wherein the responsibility for performing an action is transferred from some root source to an interested third party. For instance, `UIApplication` has delegate *methods* that provide a third party with the ability to perform operations at certain times during the applications lifetime.  It can be though of as a milestone in a timeline into which you can contribute to the story.

A controller is a totally different animal and is responsible for doing, well, the controlling.  A ViewController is charged with managing views - for loading them into memory from disk when they are needed and unloading them when they are not.  They transform content from some underlying model object into a form that is usable by your view objects, load content into your in-memory model from the disk or from the internet, and dump the contents back to disk when you save and/or quit.